# Display error with Coldfusion / Bootstrap / Select2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion, jquery-select2

I'm trying to have a select2 inside one of my ColdFusion pages, but it behaving strangely. After my document is loaded, it displays 2 "select" lists. This is my code :

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2" style="width:#span_size#px;">Search :</span>
        </div>
        <select id="test1" name="test2" class="form-control js-example-basic-single"> 
        <!--- bind="cfc:bind.getcountry()" value="value_" display="display_" bindOnLoad="yes" >--->
           <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
              <option value="CA">California</option>
              <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
              <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
              <option value="WA">Washington</option>
           </optgroup>
           <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone">
              <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
              <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
              <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
              <option value="MT">Montana</option><option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
              <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
              <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
              <option value="UT">Utah</option>
              <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
           </optgroup>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
    });
</script>
```

And this is the result (yes 1 select and 1 span !)

[image: Image of Result]

[image: Image of CSS]

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you make sure you've included the **select2 CSS** file? It seems to work fine for me, here's a fork: http://jsfiddle.net/9v2fhjap/ If you include the CSS file, the select tag (in your 2nd image having a class of *select2-hidden-accessible*) gets hidden.

Comment: Super Shashank, it was one of my css who was not good loaded ! I just have a thing to examinate , my select doesn't fill all the height of the div , do you have an idea?

Comment: Okay. What's the height of the div? Can you use the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9v2fhjap/) I provided and edit it and get back with what exactly is  that you're looking for?

Comment: It's ok , i success to it ... but finally I leave the select2 ... for performance reasons ... :)